# Alsa full duplex communication

Tags: alsa

I want to implement full duplex communication using alsa. I first wrote capture and playback programs and i am transferring data from captured process to playback process using UDP communication. It is working fine when i was running two processes where one is capturing and another is playing(consider this as half duplex from A to B) , the problem comes when i was trying to implement another half duplex(Half duplex from B to A) then I am getting **Broken Pipe error**
while reading the data from Mic. How to resolve this?. Any help, thanks in advance.

Note: I am running two processes on different systems

Comment: How does your program decide when it is time to read from the PCM device?

Comment: I am reading continuously from the device and I am writing to device using async call back(by setting avail-min)..

Comment: [Don't use async](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467710/alsa-asynchronous-playback). "Broken pipe" is EPIPE, which means that you did not read fast enough. How big are the buffers?

Comment: I am using buffer of size 1880. I have some doubts regarding reading and writing. What is the optimum size i can write or read at a time from/to the device(one period or Two periods) and after reading/writing how much time i have to wait for next reading/writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the application has to wait for a PCM device, it goes to sleep and gets woken up at the next period boundary. Therefore, the optimal size to read/write is one period (or a multiple of that).

You should read/write sample data as soon as some frames are available.

To reduce the chances of an over/underrun, increase the buffer size.
(On capture devices, increasing the buffer size does not increase latency.)

Comment: "You should read/write sample data as soon as some frames are available" it means when exactly i have to read ..i have to use poll or something else

Comment: snd_pcm_read* will wait for some frames to become available (when in blocking mode).