# Alsa broken pipe error in pcm_snd_writei and pcm_snd_readi

Tags: linux, audio, voip, alsa

I am trying to write a full-duplex voip program with alsa api. I have some errors which I don't know what they happen. I call the program as `./prog -l` or `./prog -c ipaddress`. Here is general structure of the algorithm I use,

```
// all the buffers
// all the alsa device variables
// variables for udp
// all set here (alsa, udp)
snd_pcm_start(capture)
if(listen){ // if -l is chosen
    //bind socket
    while(1){
        recvfrom()
        snd_pcm_writei(playback)
        snd_pcm_readi(capture)
        sendto()
    }
}

if(call){ // if -c ipaddress is chosen
    while(1){
        snd_pcm_readi(capture)
        sendto()
        recvfrom()
        snd_pcm_writei(playback)
    }
}
```

Alsa variables I use are **48 khz rate, 2 channels, signed 16 bit** for both input and output.

I get `broken pipe` error in both `snd_pcm_writei` and `snd_pcm_readi` functions that run under `if(listen)`.

What's interesting is I have a one-way version of the same program with the **exact same layout, alsa parameters and alsa functions** and it works but this one doesn't. Does anybody know what the reason could be?

Below one-way architecture works OK, either on the same host or on different hosts

**recorder**

```
// all the buffers
// capture alsa device - microphone
// udp socket
// set everything
snd_pcm_start(capture)
while(1){
    snd_pcm_readi(capture)
    sendto()
}
```

**player**

```
// all the buffers
// playback alsa device - speakers
// udp socket
// set everything
// bind socket
snd_pcm_writei(playback)// without this, snd_pcm_start gives an error
snd_pcm_start(playback) // without this, snd_pcm_writei gives broken pipe error
while(1){
    recvfrom()
    snd_pcm_writei(playback)
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Alsa full duplex communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039573/alsa-full-duplex-communication)

Comment: No, it does not. I already tried what's explained there and it did not work. I keep getting `broken pipe` errors.

Comment: You are calling snd_pcm_readi and writei sequentially. You must poll both devices and handle the first one that is ready. (Also do the same for the socket.)

Comment: I thought `snd_pcm_readi` and `snd_pcm_writei` are synchronous functions as well as `sendto` and `recvfrom`. Why is there a need for polling? As far as I know, polling is used for asynchronous functions. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You should configure all devices for non-blocking mode, because you do not know which one of them is ready first.

Comment: Do you know how half-duplex version works without polling?

Comment: I mean, aren't `snd_pcm_writei` and `snd_pcm_readi` blocking operations?

Comment: @CL. Would `snd_pcm_link` be a solution for the problem? It is used for capture and playback at the same time. However, after my trials I discovered that it doesn't work well when the sockets are involved.

Comment: These functions are non-blocking when the device is in non-blocking mode, after calling `snd_pcm_nonblock`.

Comment: @CL. I did use polling and it worked. However, I still don't understand how polling helps with the issue.